# Erro ao enviar notificação push com Firebase-messaging

Tags: java, android-studio, eclipse, firebase-cloud-messaging

Estou usando o método abaixo que funcionava:

```
public void enviaNotificacaoDenuncia(String mensagem, String token) {
        Sender sender = new Sender(apiKey);
        Message message = new Message.Builder()
                .addData("message", mensagem)
                //.addData("denuncia", getGson().toJson(denuncia, DetalheDenuncia.class))
                .build();
        try {
            Result result = sender.send(message, token, 3);

            System.out.println(result.getCanonicalRegistrationId());
            System.out.println(result.getErrorCodeName());
            System.out.println(result.getMessageId());
            //System.out.println(denuncia.getTokenGCM().substring(0, 10));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

agora aparece o erro abaixo:

```
com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 400(Error=DeprecatedEndpoint)
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:211)
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:125)
    at com.t2ti.cardapio.Cardapio.enviaNotificacaoDenuncia(Cardapio.java:398)
    at com.t2ti.cardapio.Cardapio.insereDetalheDenuncia(Cardapio.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:121)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ago 23, 2019 3:47:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFORMAÇÕES: Reloading Context with name [/CardapioWebService] has started
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui utilizando o método abaixo:
[Crédito](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v29x4dKNBJw&list=PLp4M7A4lZsZ-aNC6fJwvyzUdnAib7c6Yy)

```
public void sendToTokenFcm(String tkn, String corpo)  {
        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","key=sua key");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            json.put("to", tkn);


            JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
            info.put("title", "Secretaria do Meio Ambiente");   // Notification title
            info.put("body", corpo); // Notification body

            json.put("notification", info);

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(json.toString());
            wr.flush();
            conn.getInputStream();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log.d("Error",""+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


       // return null;
      }
```

[image: Como ficou]

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, o Google Cloude Messaging (GCM) foi depreciado, no lugar o google aconselha a utilizar o Cloud Messaging with Firebase.
Veja a documentação do [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq).
E sobre como utilizar o [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).